# How to write multiple files from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with 400,000 items in it, whose keys are DNA names and values are DNA sequences.
I want to divide the dictionary into 40 text files with 10,000 items in each of the files.

**Here are my codes:**

```
record_dict # my DNA dictionary

keys_in_dict #the list of the keys

for keys in keys_in_dict:

    outhandle = open("D:\\Research\\Transcriptome_sequences\\input{0}.fasta".format (?????), "w")
```

What should I put in place of `(?????)`? How do I finish this loop?

UPDATE:
Hey fellows,
Thank you for your help. Now I can make multiple files from a dictionary. However, when I tried to make multiple files directly from the original file instead of making a dictionary first, I had problems. The codes only generate one file with the first item in it. What did I do wrong? Here are my codes:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
handle = open("D:/Research/Transcriptome_sequences/differentially_expressed_genes.fasta","rU")

filesize = 100        # number of entries per file
filenum = 0
itemcount = 0


for record in SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta") :
    if not itemcount % filesize:
        outhandle = open("D:/Research/Transcriptome_sequences/input{0}.fasta".format(filenum), "w")
        SeqIO.write(record, outhandle, "fasta")
        filenum += 1
        itemcount += 1      
outhandle.close()
```

Comment: Are you just asking how to get the value corresponding to each key `keys`? That's just `record_dict[keys]`. (Also, naming the variable that holds each key, one at a time, with the plural `keys` seems misleading…)

Comment: As a side note, you almost never need a list of the keys of a dictionary; you can just loop over `for key in record_dict:`. Or you can loop over `for key, value in record_dict.items():` and not need to then do `record_dict[key]` inside the loop.

Comment: Thank you, abarnert. Simply speaking, I have a large file with 400,000 items in it and I want to divide this file into 40 smaller files with 10,000 items in each small files.

Comment: use enumerate, when you reach 10000-20000 etc.., create and write to a new file

Comment: How do I do it? Sorry, I am a newbie to python.

Comment: How do I write multiple files with different names at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not be the fastest solution, but I think the most straightforwared way is to keep track of lines and open a file every 10,000 iterations through loop.

I assume you are writing out fasta or something.

Otherwise, you could slice the list `[:10000]` beforehand and generate a chunk of output to write all at once with one command (which would be much faster). Even as it is, you might want to build up the string by concatenating through the loop and then writing that one monstrous string out with a single `.write` command for each file.

```
itemcount=0
filesize = 10000
filenum = 0
filehandle = ""

for keys in keys_in_dict:
    # check if it is time to open a new file, 
    # whenever itemcount/filesize has no remainder
    if not itemcount % filesize: 
        if filehandle:
            filehandle.close()
        filenum+=1
        PathToFile = "D:/Research/Transcriptome_sequences/input{0}.fasta".format(filenum)
        filehandle = open(PathToFile,'w')
    filehandle.write(">{0}\n{1}\n".format(keys,record_dict[keys])
    itemcount += 1

filehandle.close()
```

---

EDIT: Here is a more efficient way to do it (time-wise, not memory-wise), only writing once per file (40x total) instead of with each line (400,000 times). As always, **check your output**, especially making sure that the first and last sequences are included in the output and the last file is written properly.

```
filesize = 10        # number of entries per file
filenum = 0
filehandle = ""
OutString = ""

print record_dict
for itemcount,keys in enumerate(keys_in_dict):
    # check if it is time to open a new file, 
    # whenever itemcount/filesize has no remainder
    OutString += ">{0}\n{1}\n".format(keys,record_dict[keys])
    if not itemcount % filesize: 
        if filehandle:
            filehandle.write(OutString)
            filehandle.close()
            OutString =""
        filenum+=1
        PathToFile = "D:/Research/Transcriptome_sequences/input{0}.fasta".format(filenum)
        filehandle = open(PathToFile,'w')


filehandle.write(OutString)
filehandle.close()
```

Comment: That's right. I'm writing fast format. Another question is the total sequence number may not be an integer. It could be 399,xxx something.

Comment: It says filehandle not defined. Do I have to move the filehandle line before the if filehandle line?

Comment: What do I put in the filehandle.write("OUTPUT TEXT HERE\n")? It creates each file for my each gene.

Comment: Finally, I did it. I am just too stupid to understand your code, beroe. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're not too stupid..! I just used shorthand since I didn't know your exact requirements. Doesn't matter if total number is 399,000 or whatever -- that last file will just have fewer than 10k entries. I missed initializing the blank `filehandle`... should be fixed now. I also made a quick stab at providing the output as fasta format...

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 10000
sections = (record_dict.items()[i:i+n] for i in xrange(0,len(record_dict),n))
for ind, sec in enumerate(sections):
    with open("D:/Research/Transcriptome_sequences/input{0}.fasta".format(ind), "w") as f1:
        for k,v in sec:
            f1.write("{} {}\n".format(k,v))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Padraic. I'm trying it now.

Comment: Doesn't that just write out every 10,000th item, and not the rest?

Comment: It says "writelines() arguments must be a sequence of strings"

Comment: I need it to write 10,000 items into one file and next 10,000 into next file, etch and put whatever left into the last file

Comment: @Gray, I changed the code, replace `n` in scetions with the amount of items you want in each file, because you have non strings unless we call map we have to iterate over and use format

Comment: no worries, you're welcome, without seeing your data it is hard to know exactly the format you want but should be close to what you need

Comment: I think your chunking method is going to be more efficient, but even with this, I'd build the output string and just do one `.write()` per file. Also, do you mean `[i:i,+n]` or just `[i:i+n]`?

Comment: @beroe, I mean `[i:i+n]` it is not numpy, also the OP has key values pairings so I presume he/she wants them on separate lines not 10000 k/v's on one line

Comment: Well, you have the extra comma in your code. ;^)  Regarding building output,  I put the `\n` into the string as it is built, so it is not all one line in the file. See my second code chunk for what I am talking about. Regards....

Answer (score 0):

Making use of the built-in module/function, [itertools.tee](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html), could solve this elegantly.

```
import itertools

for (idx, keys2) in enumerate(itertools.tee(keys_in_dict, 40)):
    with open('filename_prefix_%02d.fasta' % idx, 'w') as fout:
        for key in keys2:
            fout.write(...)
```

Quoted from the doc for your reference:

> itertools.tee(iterable[, n=2]) Return n independent iterators from a
>   single iterable.
>
> Once tee() has made a split, the original iterable should not be used
>   anywhere else; otherwise, the iterable could get advanced without the
>   tee objects being informed.
>
> This itertool may require significant auxiliary storage (depending on
>   how much temporary data needs to be stored). In general, if one
>   iterator uses most or all of the data before another iterator starts,
>   it is faster to use list() instead of tee().

Comment: Nice, Drake. Another way of doing this. Very enlightening!